# How to filter a date using filter_var_array

Tags: php

I have a csv file that contains lines with a format as follows:

```
Name;timestamp;floatValue
```

The file has over than 20000 lines, and I want to filter each value of each line. I tried using this code :

```
$args=array(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        $testing = filter_var_array($line,$args);
        var_dump($testing);
}
```

I get this error:

```
 filter_var_array(): Numeric keys are not allowed in the definition array
```

So I have 2 problems here:

- Why do I get this error ? In fact, as I can't get from the line an array with keys and values, I don't know how to still use the `filter_var_array`
- How to combine filtering strings, floats with a date ? is it possible to skip the date in the middle to filter it after separetly by using `DateTime::CreateFromFormat` ? I checked this [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp) but there is no filter for dates.

> :::EDIT:::

What about this:

```
  $data = array(
        'name' => $line[0],
        'timestamp' => $line[1],
        'value' => $line[2]);

        $args=array(
          'name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
          'timestamp' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
          'value' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $testing = filter_var_array($data,$args);
        var_dump($testing);
```

Kindly tell me if it's a good approche.

Comment: @StuartWagner I know there are more fields to include but my array that I want to filter does not have keys and values (indexed array)

Comment: `filter_var_array()` requires an input array with string keys. You might need a different approach if you don't have such keys.

Comment: @StuartWagner Then why this example works : 
`<?php
$data = array(
                'php',
                'javascript',
                'programming');

$myinputs = filter_var_array($data,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

var_dump($myinputs); 
?>`

Comment: That works because you're only specifying one filter, not an array of filters like in your original code sample.

Comment: @StuartWagner kindly check the edit please

Comment: That should work. Have you tried?

Comment: @StuartWagner Yes, It worked. I still look for how to check the date though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`filter_var_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php) works with associative arrays, not numeric,

you have to transform your arrays by adding associative keys

```
$args = array('string' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'int' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 'float' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$keys = array('string', 'int', 'float'); 
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $testing = filter_var_array(array_combine($keys, $line), $args);
    var_dump($testing);
}
```

Comment: The keys name doesn't matter as long as every key name matches the filter associated with

Comment: that's interesting